# how to remove svn:eol-style propety on a file

Tags: svn, version, controls

If svn:eol-style property is set on a file, I see temporary files when I use vimdiff as the diff-cmd tool.

This was set due to a user from windows setting the property with the auto prop enable in his svn config file.  I asked him and he has agreed.
This, however, doesn't remove the svn-eol keyword property for the files which already has the property set.

However now, the questions are:
-- how do i remove it for the files for which the svn-eol keyword property is already set ?.
--Also, how do i enforce on a repository level that svn-eol keyword property is never set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Deleting a property

You can delete a property using the `propdel` subcommand:

```
$ svn help propdel
```

> `propdel (pdel, pd)`: Remove a property from files, dirs, or revisions.
>
> ```
>  usage: 1. propdel PROPNAME [PATH...]
>         2. propdel PROPNAME --revprop -r REV [TARGET]
> ```
>
> 1. Removes versioned props in working copy.
> 2. Removes unversioned remote prop on repos revision.
>      `TARGET` only determines which repository to access.

#### Getting a property

That's what the `propget` subcommand is there for:

```
$ svn help propget
```

> `propget (pget, pg)`: Print the value of a property on files, dirs, or revisions.
>
> ```
>  usage: 1. propget PROPNAME [TARGET[@REV]...]
>         2. propget PROPNAME --revprop -r REV [TARGET]
> ```
>
> 1. Prints versioned props. If specified, `REV` determines in which
>      revision the target is first looked up.
> 2. Prints unversioned remote prop on repos revision.
>      `TARGET` only determines which repository to access.

#### Forbidding setting of a property

This, I think, you can't really operate by setting *something* like a property on a repository, but supposedly you should be able to arm the repository on the server with [a pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) which is a script (or any other kind of executable program actually) which performs the necessary checks on the changes to be committed and fails the commit if it detects a developer had managed to set the `svn:eol-style` property on one of the files, and attempted to commit this change.

I have no idea as to how exactly to implement this check but supposedly given the pointer above you shold be able to figure this out.